# python read xml file and convert into csv file

Tags: python, parsexml

I am trying to convert xml file into csv file. How to read and parse xml file and convert into csv? Is there any package to convert xml into csv.

```
<services>
    <service>
        <ServiceID>1</ServiceID>
        <ServiceName>eVoting Booth</ServiceName>
    </service>
    <service>
        <ServiceID>2</ServiceID>
        <ServiceName>Justice of the Peace</ServiceName>
    </service>
    <service>
        <ServiceID>3</ServiceID>
        <ServiceName>Library</ServiceName>
    </service>
        <service>
        <ServiceID>4</ServiceID>
        <ServiceName>Customer Service</ServiceName>
    </service>
    <service>
        <ServiceID>5</ServiceID>
        <ServiceName>Migrant Service</ServiceName>
    </service>
</services>
```

I want result as

```
ServiceID | ServiceName
1         | Library
2         | Justice of the Peace
```

Comment: What have you tried? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this could work:

```py
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ServiceID" : tree.xpath('/services/service/ServiceID/text()'),
    "ServiceName" : tree.xpath('/services/service/ServiceName/text()')
})

df.to_csv("output.csv", sep="|", index = None)
```

this produces

```
ServiceID|ServiceName
1|eVoting Booth
2|Justice of the Peace
3|Library
4|Customer Service
5|Migrant Service
```